# Parsing this string with regex PHP

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace

I have string in format as below:

ABC 318 XY2388

I tried to use preg replace function in PHP with Regex but having no knowledge of reg ex I am not getting anywhere.

I want above string to end up like ABC 318/XY 2388

So the rule is:

- Keep the first ABC (first batch of letters) untouched.
- Put a space between letter(s) and number occurring after ABC.
- replace space between second batch of numbers and letters with forward slash

I will appreciate any help on this.

Comment: What about the XY? Are they removed?

Comment: sorry modified the question. Really sorry about this.

Comment: What kind of letters/digits? Unicode? Only ASCII? Also, there already is a space between `ABC` and `318`, but not between `XY` and `2388` - that doesn't match your description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code changes the string using the corrected rule/example you are giving:

```
  $input = "ABC 318 XY2388";
  $output = preg_replace("/([A-Z]*) (\d*) ([A-Z]*)(\d*)/","$1 $2/$3 $4", $input);
  echo $output;
```

Result: `ABC 318/XY 2388`

Comment: Slightly changed the question. Sorry about this.

Comment: Thanks a lot!, If the first batch of letters were unknown then what happens?

Comment: I mean if the ABC was not know then how can I solve it?, in future it may be ABB, AVC or anything

Comment: Modified the answer so the first batch is dynamic (in the previous answer, it was fixed to "ABC") :)

Comment: `[\d]` is unnecessary, it is better written as `\d` without the `[]`.

Comment: Thanks. Removed the `[]`.